# How to change StatusBar Style for LAContext

Tags: ios, swift, lacontext

i have implemented `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` in my application.

I have implemeted biometric authentication in my application.
but the issue is my `UIViewController` has `.lightContent` and when biometric dialog presents for authentication it has `.default` style so please guide me how can i change the `statusBar` style of biometric authentication controller.

here is the reference screens.

**1.** `UIViewController` with Light Content
[image]

**2.** Biometric authentication 
[image]

please guide me how to change biometric authentication `statusBar` style?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @ChikabuZ, Not yet.

Answer (score 0):

Override this method on the `ViewController`:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this method in `ViewController` and you may need to set `myViewController.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true` on the view controller to be presented modally.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can manually change status bar style when biometric authentication controller open

```
 UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

or

```
  UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
```